# ip configuration could not be reserved (no available address timeout etc.)

Tags: linux, networking

I am running VMware Fusion with multiple VMs on it. But recently all but one of 4 VMs has internet connection. The network devices on my centos machine is available but I can't bring it and the `DHCP` doesn't seem to provide `IP` addresses.

When I cat `etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-ens33` the configuration is as follow:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
PROXY_METHOD="none"
BROWSER_ONLY="no"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DEFROUT="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUT="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="ens33"
UUID="b8cc7497-b5c5-4303-9e34-3fb36aed04ab"
DEVICE="ens33"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

And when I try to connect the `ens33` device i get the following error:

```
nmcli device connect ens33
```

**output:**

> Error: connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved(no available addresses, timeout, etc.).

I looked up the error on RedHat access and i couldn't find a viable solution. Yet one of my VMs with a static IP and the following `network script` configuration works just fine and connect to the internet:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
PROXY_METHOD="none"
BROWSER_ONLY="no"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="ens33"
UUID="87d3aec8-983c-4bf5-bb0e-4bb8d3a090d2"
DEVICE="ens33"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR="192.168.4.200"
PREFIX="24"
GATEWAY="192.168.4.2"
DNS1="8.8.8.8"
IPV6_PRIVACY="no"
ZONE=public
```

Your help will be very much apriciated.

Comment: Do all your VMs live in the same private network? Are you sure the DHCP IP range does not conflict with your static assignments? What does DHCP's log tell on the problematic host?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (except in VMWare Workstation and not Fusion), and in my case, Linux-side setup was okay. Static IP didn't work either.

The problem was in VMWare networking.

I've had a bunch of VPNs, inactive Wi-Fi connections and other virtual adapters in host OS (Windows), and VMWare was auto-routing bridged network to the wrong adapter. I switched VMnet0 from automatic to specific physical Ethernet adapter (using Virtual Network Editor), and that solved the problem.

Comment: go to `Virtual Network Editor`  -> `VMnet0` -> Briged to(combobox) : now Select the correct adapter

Answer (score -1):

try like this :

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
PROXY_METHOD="none"
BROWSER_ONLY="no"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUT="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUT="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="ens33"
UUID="b8cc7497-b5c5-4303-9e34-3fb36aed04ab"
DEVICE="ens33"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

Comment: Please post text as text, not as an image.